# Programatically creating Pivot table in excel workbook with Odata as source

Tags: c#, excel, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table in excel workbook using C#. The source is Odata Feed URL. 
I have written following code:

```
    string connectionString = @"DATAFEED;Data Source=" + odataURL + ";Namespaces to Include=*;Max Received Message Size=4398046511104;Integrated Security=Basic;User ID=" + "xyz" + ";Password=" + "bvby" + ";Persist Security Info=true;Base Url=" + odataURL;
    Excel.PivotCache pivotCache = app.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal, Type.Missing);
    pivotCache.Connection = connectionString;
```

It throw following exception when I do `pivotCache.Connection`:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
HResult=-2146827284
Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
Source=""
ErrorCode=-2146827284
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache.set_Connection(Object value)
at ConsoleApplication2.Program.createWorkBookHelper(Application app, Workbook workbook, String odataURL, String nameOfWorkBook) 
in d:\ReportingApp\Dev\PDS\Excel Plugin\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 36`
```